# Using Network.HTTP.Simple.httpJSON in ghci

Tags: haskell

The [Receiving JSON](https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client) example works fine. But why the execution of `httpJSON` doesn't work in `ghci`?

```
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> import           Network.HTTP.Simple
λ> :t httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get"
λ> x <- httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get"

<interactive>:97:6: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘httpJSON’
      prevents the constraint ‘(aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON
                                  a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON Value
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
        instance (aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON a,
                  aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON b) =>
                 aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
        instance aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON.FromJSON Ordering
          -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.0.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
        ...plus 24 others
        ...plus 53 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO ::
                                  forall a. IO a -> IO a’, namely
        ‘httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get"’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command:
        x <- GHC.GHCi.ghciStepIO :: forall a. IO a -> IO a
             (httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get")
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with GHCi in particular. The return type of `httpJSON` is polymorphic. Without additional type information (i.e., a use site for `x` which constrains it to a monomorphic type, or a type signature on `x`, or one on `httpJSON`) there is no way to infer the type. In the example, that information is provided by the fragment `(getResponseBody response :: Value)`. Try `x :: Response Value <- ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user2407038's hint I figured out:

```
λ> :t liftM (\x -> getResponseBody x :: Value) (httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get")
liftM (\x -> getResponseBody x :: Value) (httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get")
  :: MonadIO m => m Value                                           
λ> liftM (\x -> getResponseBody x :: Value) (httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get")
Object (fromList [("origin",String "158.181.77.67"),("args",Object (fromList [])),("url",String "http://httpbin.org/get"),("headers",Obj
g "close"),("Host",String "httpbin.org")]))])
```