# What in the parse body code makes the header read to not fail?

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to build a simple web scraper to get some corpus of text from wikipedia. I would like to use their REST API building a simple HTTP client in Haskell.

To do so, I've turned to the Network.HTTP.Simple package.  In their [tutorial](https://haskell-lang.org/library/http-client) they provide the following snippet, which i can get to run nicely.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --install-ghc --resolver lts-5.13 runghc
    --package http-conduit
    --package yaml
-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Data.Aeson            (Value)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as S8
import qualified Data.Yaml             as Yaml
import           Network.HTTP.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
    response <- httpJSON "http://httpbin.org/get"

    putStrLn $ "The status code was: " ++
               show (getResponseStatusCode response)
    print $ getResponseHeader "Content-Type" response
    S8.putStrLn $ Yaml.encode (getResponseBody response :: Value)
```

Trying to understand the code I commented out the last line (the one starting `S8.putStrLn`..., and now the code breaks. The error is

```
No instance for (Yaml.FromJSON a0) arising from a use of ‘httpJSON’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Yaml.FromJSON
                 aeson-1.2.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.DotNetTime
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      instance Yaml.FromJSON Value
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      instance Yaml.FromJSON
                 attoparsec-0.13.1.0:Data.Attoparsec.Number.Number
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.2.1.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      ...plus 78 others
```

So my questions are: 
**(1)** So my guess is that the `getResponseBody` forces the type signature of `httpJSON`, so the ambiguity is lifted. But how?
**(2)** Can I disambiguate the expression without calling `getResponseBody`? What options do I have to fix the return type of polymorphic functions?

**Edit:** I am running this with `cabal run` since i have not installed Stack. I did not expect that to change things, but who knows... Might provide a clue.

Comment: Possible duplicate for question **(1)**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724662/using-network-http-simple-httpjson-in-ghci but it still doesnt help me with **(2)**

Comment: Why downvote? Is there something I could have improved in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Type checking

We have this signature: [`getResponseBody :: Response a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.2.3.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html#v:getResponseBody).

At first, just after `httpJSON`, we have `response :: Response a0` for some yet unknown `a0`.

Then we write `getResponseBody response`, which has type `a0`, still unknown.

Then we annotate `getResponseBody response :: Value`, so `a0 ~ Value`, and now instance resolution has a concrete type to work with.

#### Alternative ways to restrict the type of `response`

You can annotate the `response` value directly wherever it gets used, for instance you could write `getResponseStatusCode (response :: Response Value)` in the middle of your snippet.

With the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, you can also annotate the pattern which binds it: `(response :: Response Value) <- httpJSON "..."`.

The `a0` type variable also occurs in the result type of `httpJSON`, so you can also annotate it.

```
response <- httpJSON "..." :: IO (Response Value)
```

With `TypeApplications`, here are more alternatives, any one should be sufficient for the type checker to deduce `a0 ~ Value`:

```
response <- httpJSON @_ @Value "..."

getResponseStatusCode @Value response
getResponseHeader @Value "..." response
getResponseBody @Value response
```